# Cannot Submit App to iTunes Connect

Tags: validation, xcode5, app-store-connect

Basically, I had an app that I designed for xcode 3 that I converted to xcode 4 that I converted to Xcode 5 that I now want to release. I did this perfectly and got everything working on the simulator and my device, but when I tried to submit it to itunes connect it, I got a bunch of weird errors and warnings. Could someone just explain to me what they mean? Also, if anyone wants me to post code, just tell me what code to post. Thanks and here are the weird errors and warnings (by the way I received these errors/warnings during validation, if that helps):

[image]

Comment: Looks like it says you're missing the 120x120 app icon. Are you?

Comment: yep that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured out the problem. I just needed an icon of size 120 x 120, the rest of the errors were just due to that.